# Check whether User is a bot or not in MySql

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, data-analysis, having

I'm doing data analysis on Instagram user database, I need to find users who are Bots by checking which user has liked all photos in site as liking all photo is not practically possible for a real user.

Table Format

```
like
-- 
user_id
photo_id
created_at
```

```
photos 
--
id
image_url
user_id
created_at
```

```
user
--
id
username
created_at
```

---- Tried ----

```sql
SELECT photos.user_id, count(photos.user_id) AS users_in_photos, count(likes.user_id) AS users_in_likes
FROM photos
INNER JOIN likes
ON photos.user_id = likes.user_id
group by photos.user_id;
```

With this I expected to get users who are in both photos and like table, and by seeing their count I can determine who are bots.

Comment: The case you are testing for seems VERY specific, will catch only bots who do that one thing, and will also false-flag a user who actually does like all pictures. But, your algorithm would check for that . . . but what is your question?

Comment: What you said is my question itself to Flag all users who have liked all photos. It will not accidentally flag a user as a user can't like thousands of photos. I apologize if my question was a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of all photos can be obtained with:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM photos
```

Assuming there are no duplicate combinations of `user_id` and `photo_id` in the table `likes`, use aggregation and filter the bots in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM likes
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM photos);
```

Comment: I never thought it can be done this way too. I was trying to solve it using joins, if you have a solution using joins please do share.